# Why ia Pyinstaller not working with Pycharm?

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, exe, pong

I built the pong game with Kivyin Pycharm, and want to export it as a .exe standalone. I tried Pyinstaller and this happened:

41727 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes39.dll
42028 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pythoncom39.dll
42081 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_decimal
.pyd
42128 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\select.p
yd
42181 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_overlap
ped.pyd
42244 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_queue.p
yd
42297 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_ctypes.
pyd
42360 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_multipr
ocessing.pyd
42382 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\pyexpat.
pyd
42445 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\unicoded
ata.pyd
42482 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_asyncio
.pyd
42544 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_hashlib
.pyd
42598 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_lzma.py
d
42645 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_bz2.pyd

42714 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_socket.
pyd
42799 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_ssl.pyd

42845 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32\win32trace.pyd
42983 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\win32ui.pyd
43146 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32_win32sysloader.pyd
43300 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd
43362 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_uuid.py
d
43431 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32comext\shell\shell.pyd
43516 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\cgl_backend\cgl_gl.cp
39-win_amd64.pyd
43547 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\cgl_backend\cgl_debug
.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
43585 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\audio\audio_sdl2.cp39-win
*amd64.pyd
43685 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text_text_sdl2.cp39-win*
amd64.pyd
43748 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\instructions.cp39-win
_amd64.pyd
43786 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lib\gstplayer_gstplayer.cp39-
win_amd64.pyd
43848 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy_event.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
43886 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\shader.cp39-win_amd64
.pyd
43933 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp39-win_amd64
.pyd
43986 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\weakproxy.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
44033 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\tesselator.cp39-win_a
md64.pyd
44049 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\transformation.cp39-w
in_amd64.pyd
44086 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\vertex.cp39-win_amd64
.pyd
44133 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\gl_instructions.cp39-
win_amd64.pyd
44165 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\vbo.cp39-win_amd64.py
d
44218 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\context.cp39-win_amd6
4.pyd
44265 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_layout.cp39-win
_amd64.pyd
44303 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\cgl_backend\cgl_glew.
cp39-win_amd64.pyd
44350 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\opengl_utils.cp39-win
*amd64.pyd
44465 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\vertex_instructions.c
p39-win_amd64.pyd
44503 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\fbo.cp39-win_amd64.py
d
44566 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_info.cp39-w
in_amd64.pyd
44619 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32\win32file.pyd
44836 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\stencil_instructions.
cp39-win_amd64.pyd
44867 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\compiler.cp39-win_amd
64.pyd
44905 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\texture.cp39-win_amd6
4.pyd
44952 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs_element
tree.pyd
45005 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\context_instructions.
cp39-win_amd64.pyd
45036 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\opengl.cp39-win_amd64
.pyd
45068 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\cgl.cp39-win_amd64.py
d
45105 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\cgl_backend\cgl_sdl2.
cp39-win_amd64.pyd
45152 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\scissor_instructions.
cp39-win_amd64.pyd
45190 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\svg.cp39-win_amd64.py
d
45221 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\clipboard_clipboard_sdl2
.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
45253 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window_window_sdl2.cp39-
win_amd64.pyd
45306 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image_img_sdl2.cp39-win*
amd64.pyd
45353 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32\win32gui.pyd
45406 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\cgl_backend\cgl_mock.
cp39-win_amd64.pyd
45437 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy_clock.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
45469 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\properties.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
46594 INFO: Looking for eggs
46594 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
46594 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Users\Utilizador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\py
thon.exe
46594 WARNING:   Reason: 'The file is empty'
Traceback (most recent call last):
46594 WARNING: stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
46594 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in *run_module
*as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
46594 WARNING: stderr:     return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
46594 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
46594 WARNING: stderr:     exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Utilizador\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
46594 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\Utilizador\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 114, in run
46594 WARNING: stderr:   File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 114, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
46594 WARNING: stderr:     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 65, in run_build
46594 WARNING: stderr:   File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 65, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
46594 WARNING: stderr:     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in main
46594 WARNING: stderr:   File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
46594 WARNING: stderr:     build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 672, in build
46610 WARNING: stderr:   File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 672, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
46610 WARNING: stderr:     exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "C:\Users\Utilizador\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.spec", line 6, in 
46610 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\Utilizador\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.spec", line 6, in 
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
46610 WARNING: stderr:     a = Analysis(['main.py'],
File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in **init**
46610 WARNING: stderr:   File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in **init**
self.**postinit**()
46610 WARNING: stderr:     self.**postinit**()
File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in **postinit**
46610 WARNING: stderr:   File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in _*postinit*
_
self.assemble()
46610 WARNING: stderr:     self.assemble()
File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 476, in assemble
46610 WARNING: stderr:   File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 476, in assemble
self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
46610 WARNING: stderr:     self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 569, in _check_python_library
46610 WARNING: stderr:   File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 569, in _check_pyth
on_library
python_lib = bindepend.get_python_library_path()
46610 WARNING: stderr:     python_lib = bindepend.get_python_library_path()
File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 956, in get_python_library_path
46610 WARNING: stderr:   File "c:\users\utilizador\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 956, in get_python_lib
rary_path
raise IOError(msg)
46610 WARNING: stderr:     raise IOError(msg)
OSError: Python library not found: libpython39m.dll, libpython3.9.dll, libpython3.9m.dll, python39.dll, libpython39.dll
46610 WARNING: stderr: OSError: Python library not found: libpython39m.dll, libpython3.9.dll, libpython3.9m.dll, python39.dll, libpython39.dll
This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
46625 WARNING: stderr:     This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.
46625 WARNING: stderr:     This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.

46625 WARNING: stderr:
* On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to install Python development packages
46625 WARNING: stderr:     * On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to install Python development packages
* apt-get install python3-dev
46625 WARNING: stderr:       * apt-get install python3-dev
* apt-get install python-dev
46625 WARNING: stderr:       * apt-get install python-dev
* If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)
46625 WARNING: stderr:     * If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)

46625 WARNING: stderr:

This keeps appearing. i've tried with a lot of different code and projects in Pycharm, but it never works. I've tried with different versions and different commands, but in the end it's always the same.

I get the 'dist' folder but it's empty, always empty.
This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
)
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        # bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        # bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        # went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y
class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

open cmd and do:    cd (directory where python file is)   example: cd desktop

Then do     pyinstaller --onefile name.py